# Maximum call stack size exceeded when click on the card to trigger button inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a card detail order, I want the whole card to be clickable and it will trigger a button inside the card to bring up the modal details. I've made the code as below but there is a **Maximum call stack size exceeded** error and also my `console.log('clicked')` is triggered hundred times.

how to handle this? please help me

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".order-list-detail-container").each(function() {
    $(this).on("click", function() {
      console.log('clicked')
      $(this).find('.order-detail-trigger').click()
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="order-list-detail-container" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
  <button class="hidden order-detail-trigger" hx-get="/order-detail" hx-trigger="click" hx-target="#orderDetailModal">Detail Trigger</button>

  <!-- Date -->
  <div class="date-container">
    <span style="display: inline-block; width: 33%" class="date">9 Nov 2021</span>
    <div style="width: 33%;"></div>
    <div style="width: 33%;"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- SO Number, Status, Price -->
  <div class="order-info-container" style="display:flex; border-bottom: 1px solid gainsboro; margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <div class="order-info with-margin-right" style="width: 33%">
      <div class="label">Shipping Order Number</div>
      <div class="value no-order-value" style="color: #cb4645;">T123456</div>
    </div>
    <div class="order-info" style="width: 33%">
      <div class="label">Status</div>
      <div class="value" style="color: #cb4645;">
        In Process
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="order-info-grand-total" style="width: 33%; text-align: right;">
      <div class="label">Total</div>
      <div class="value">$1200</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="products-list">
    <div class="product-container">
      <div class="product-inner-container">
        <div class="product-info-container">
          <div class="product-name">Grinder 6", RBG6</div>
          <div class="product-catalog-code">RBG6</div>
          <div class="product-detail-info">
            <div class="product-metadata">
              <span class="product-qty">3 Product</span>
              <div class="product-weight">(8 kg)</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>    
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>

</div>

<div class="order-list-detail-container">
  <button class="hidden order-detail-trigger" hx-get="/order-detail" hx-trigger="click" hx-target="#orderDetailModal">Detail Trigger</button>

  <!-- Date -->
  <div class="date-container">
    <span style="display: inline-block; width: 33%" class="date">9 Nov 2021</span>
    <div style="width: 33%;"></div>
    <div style="width: 33%;"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- SO Number, Status, Price -->
  <div class="order-info-container" style="display:flex; border-bottom: 1px solid gainsboro; margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <div class="order-info with-margin-right" style="width: 33%">
      <div class="label">Shipping Order Number</div>
      <div class="value no-order-value" style="color: #cb4645;">T127890</div>
    </div>
    <div class="order-info" style="width: 33%">
      <div class="label">Status</div>
      <div class="value" style="color: #cb4645;">
        In Process
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="order-info-grand-total" style="width: 33%; text-align: right;">
      <div class="label">Total</div>
      <div class="value">$1800</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="products-list">
    <div class="product-container">
      <div class="product-inner-container">
        <div class="product-info-container">
          <div class="product-name">Grinder 8", RBG8</div>
          <div class="product-catalog-code">RBG8</div>
          <div class="product-detail-info">
            <div class="product-metadata">
              <span class="product-qty">2 Product</span>
              <div class="product-weight">(3 kg)</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>    
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: still not solving my problem @GerardoFurtado

Comment: @fikfe just wanted to know, what's the purpose of this line -> ` $(this).find('.order-detail-trigger').click();`

Comment: To find class ```.order-detail-trigger```, and do click functions @TBA

Comment: @fikfe yeah I know it's for clicking purposes, but why do you need to do that? You are clicking on the parent, and then again you are finding the child class and clicking on it, which makes this thing a never-ending loop.

Comment: i want to trigger my htmx. ```htmx-get``` is on the button, so when I click the card, the htmx trigger will also be clicked and display the order details @TBA

Comment: the second event click is unnecessary. Tell me what is the expected result of the click (what should happen), because I do not find logic in the html code

Comment: I've edited my code above. I want to trigger this button ```<button class="hidden order-detail-trigger" hx-get="/order-detail" hx-trigger="click" hx-target="#orderDetailModal">Detail Trigger</button>``` when i click a whole card @TodorMarkov

Answer (score 0):

Working example. You only need to make `trigger` for a `button` when you click `Container`. And when you click button - it's default button behavior. In both ways you will now have `hx-get` working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('.order-list-detail-container').on('click.div', function() {
   $('.order-detail-trigger').trigger('click.button');
   console.log('clicked');

});
```

**Update 1:** If you want different buttons and cards to do different stuff, add numbered ID's for buttons and DIV's use this code:

```
$('#order-list-detail-container-1').on('click.div',function(){
   $('#order-detail-trigger-1').trigger('click.button'     );
   console.log('1 button or DIV clicked');

});

$('#order-list-detail-container-2').on('click.div',function(){
   $('#order-detail-trigger-2').trigger('click.button'     );
   console.log('2 button or DIV clicked');

});

// duplicate the code block for amount of buttons with Divs you are going to have
```

**Update 2:** Added functionality to create ID dynamically to every button and DIV. So you won't need to add any ID's manually when you will create more cards! Also, every button or div click will be counted as individual click and button 1 click won't trigger button 2 clicks:

```
$('.order-detail-trigger').each(function(index) {
  $(this).attr('id', 'button-' + index);
});
  
$('.order-list-detail-container').each(function(index) {
  $(this).attr('id', 'container-' + index);
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
  
  $('.order-list-detail-container').each(function(index) {
    $('#container-' + index).on('click.div',function() {

      $('#button-' + index).trigger('click.button');

      let test = $('#container-' + index).attr('id');
      let test2 = $('#button-' + index).attr('id');
      
      //console.log('clicked');
      console.log(test + ' clicked!');
      console.log(test2 + ' AUTO clicked!');
      });
    });
});
```

[image]

Uncomment `//console.log('clicked');` to see that clicking `DIV` or `Button` - it only happens 1 time:

[image]

Comment: i want to triggering this button ```<button class="hidden order-detail-trigger" hx-get="/order-detail" hx-trigger="click" hx-target="#orderDetailModal">Detail Trigger</button>``` , why you remove that line? when i click a whole card, i also trigger that button with ```click()```

Comment: So you want in both cases: container click and button click  to fire button's click event in order to get hx-get function?

Comment: exactly, that's i want

Comment: Edited my answer. Should 100% work now. If I answered your question, don't forget to mark answer as 'answered'. Happy to help!

Comment: @fikfe is that what you wanted?

Comment: but i have a lot of cards. If I use the code you wrote above, it will only open the earliest card. If I click on the second card, the details for card 1 open

Comment: If you want multiple cards and buttons to open different URLS and actions - you need to duplicate code for each card and button. And use different ID's for cards and buttons. For example: see updated answer.

Comment: @fikfe Check for Update 2 in my answer. Edited code to make everything 100% automatic. Now if you add more containers or buttons and click on it - if you click 3 card then the details for card 3 will open.